# How to cut and merge avi videos with java

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg

I want to cut and merge some avi videos(same codec, same resolution, same fps) using java library.

Now I am trying this using Humble video(https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video), which is based on ffmpeg.

I want to use the seek function to cut the input video first, but the result is not correct.

this is my code.

```
public void cutjob(String input, String output, int starttime) {
        final Demuxer demuxer = Demuxer.make();
        final Muxer muxer = Muxer.make(output, null, "avi");
        try {
            demuxer.open(input, null, false, true, null, null);
            final MuxerFormat format = MuxerFormat.guessFormat("avi", null, null);
            int n = demuxer.getNumStreams();
            final Decoder[] decoders = new Decoder[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                final DemuxerStream ds = demuxer.getStream(i);
                decoders[i] = ds.getDecoder();
                final Decoder d = decoders[i];
                if (d != null) {
                    if (format.getFlag(MuxerFormat.Flag.GLOBAL_HEADER))
                        d.setFlag(Coder.Flag.FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER, true);
                    d.open(null, null);
                    muxer.addNewStream(d);
                }
            }
            muxer.open(null, null);

            demuxer.seek(-1, Long.MIN_VALUE, (long)starttime* Global.getDefaultTimeBase().getDenominator(), Long.MAX_VALUE, Demuxer.SeekFlag.SEEK_ANY.swigValue());
            final MediaPacket packet = MediaPacket.make();
            long dts = -1;
            while (demuxer.read(packet) >= 0) {
                System.out.println("dts:"+packet.getDts() + ",pts:"+packet.getPts());
                final Decoder d = decoders[packet.getStreamIndex()];
                if (packet.isComplete() && d != null) {
                    dts = dts == -1 ? packet.getDts() : dts;

                    packet.setDts(packet.getDts() - dts);
                    packet.setPosition(-1);
                    muxer.write(packet, false);

                }
            }
            muxer.close();
            demuxer.close();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The video source is about 190 seconds long, and I set the "starttime" as 180,
want to cut the last 10 seconds and write to a new avi file.

The output avi file is 10 seconds long, but only the last 5s of the video is correct, the first 5s seems no data.

Is there any wrong in my code.
Thanks.

Comment: My advice would be using libav or ffmpeg. no need to use wrappers. If you feel uncomfortable using ProcessBuilder or Runtime etc. you should try out [avconv4java](https://github.com/vbauer/avconv4java)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will try it.